# How to use transferTo and using progressbar in android

Tags: android, progressdialog, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

When I copy *file-A* to *folder-B* in Android, I want use `ProgressDialog(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL)`.

Example 1:

```
String mStart = "/sdcard/aaaa/";    
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mStart);    
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);  

FileChannel fin = fis.getChannel();
FileChannel fout = fos.getChannel();    
File f = new File(mStart);

fin.transferTo(0, f.length(), fout);
```

Example 2:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];    
while ((readcount = bin.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {    
    bout.write(buffer, 0, readcount);    
    publishProgress(readcount);    
}
```

If I use the second example I can use `ProgressDialog()`, but in the first example I cannot.
How can I update `ProgressDialog` when using `transferTo()` method?

Comment: this code is included AsyncTask.